# turn seconds since 2000 to a date year python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have this column that is seconds since 20000101 .when I use this code:

> ```
>   from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
>   base_date = datetime(2000, 1, 1) 
>   d = base_date + timedelta(seconds=69827596)
>   d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")***
> ```

unfortunately i dont get the correct result.i get out - '2002-03-19 04:33:16' and it should be a date in 2022..

`

Comment: 69827596 seconds is around 2 years.

Comment: Yes, you are returning the delta (69827596) of 1/1/2000 which is ~2 years. What are you trying to figure out?

Comment: Well, I think it's seconds from 20**2**0, not 20**0**0. If you add this seconds to 1 January 2020 you will get 19 March 2022.

Comment: something is off with the data . its showing as far as 2051 and as low as 2001..